# install destination error with my catkin package

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-groovy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Groovy and converted my package from rosbuild to catkin following a migration guide.
I wrote my CMakeLists.txt referenced Groovy's sources and CMakeLists.
I run catkin_make, failed about install DESTINATION.

```
Moirai@moirai:~/moirai-ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws
Source space: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws/src
Build space: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws/build
Devel space: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws/devel
Install space: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/Moirai/moirai-ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/Moirai/moirai-ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.63
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - my_package
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'my_package'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(my_package)
CMake Error at my_package/CMakeLists.txt:18 (install):
  install TARGETS given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target
  "my_package_node".
```

My CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS sensor_msgs driver_base image_proc dynamic_reconfigure camera_calibration_parsers compressed_image_transport cv_bridge rospack)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# include files
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(src/my_package_uvc)
include_directories(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include/my_package)

# create my_package_node
add_executable(my_package_node src/my_package_node.cpp  src/my_package_uvc/my_package_camera.cpp src/my_package_uvc/my_package_uvc.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_package_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS my_package_node
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

# define the project
   catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS src/my_package_uvc
   LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
   CATKIN-DEPENDS sensor_msgs driver_base image_proc dynamic_reconfigure camera_calibration_parsers compressed_image_transport cv_bridge
   DEPENDS opencv
)
<br>
Where is ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}?<br>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54173/install-destination-error-with-my-catkin-package/) by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on 2013-02-04**:
catkin_make run successfully  when I set my workspace directory as install destination.
install(TARGETS my_package_node
DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
)
I don' know how to configure "${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_package()` defines the variable `CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION` and must therefore be called before `install()`. In your case the variable has not been set and therefore the destination is empty.

Besides that your CMakeLists.txt contains several other flaws:

- the include directories are ordered badly, first add your local stuff and then global things, else header from other workspaces will overlay your header
- your include dir should not point to `src/my_package_uvc` but `src` instead, and then you should include the header with `my_package_uvc/myfile.h`.
- the argument to catkin_package() is `CATKIN_DEPENDS` not `CATKIN-DEPENDS`

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moirai](https://answers.ros.org/users/4102/moirai/) on 2013-02-05**:
Thanks for your detailed advice. I finished my package's catkin migration! Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use this template for the install macro:

```
install(TARGETS foo foo_node
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Also, in your CMakeLists.txt, I believe:

```
target_link_libraries(my_package ...
```

should be

```
target_link_libraries(my_package_node ...
```

and

```
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS src/my_package_uvc
 LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
 ...
```

should be

```
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS src/my_package_uvc
 # LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
 ...
```

UPDATE:
Really use the catkin_create-pkg command for new packages, this generates a CMakeLists.txt for you which should help you make less mistakes.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm no expert, but according to [0] you should place catkin_package before add_executable etc.
Also I would try linking my_package node instead of my_package:
target_link_libraries(my_package_node...

[0] http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering

---

Originally posted by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) with karma: 145 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1